# How to guard whole recipes without repeating guards?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to guard against re-executing of my recipe resources, when included in other recipes, using a lock file to prevent re-downloading and extracting files.

For example, consider a recipe like this:

```
execute "step1-download" do
  command "step1-command"
  not_if do ::File.exists?('/var/recipe-already-executed') end
end

execute "step2-extract" do
  command "step2-command"
  not_if do ::File.exists?('/var/recipe-already-executed') end
end
```

Is there a way to guard the recipe as a whole, to avoid repeating the guard in every resource of the recipe?

Comment: Code? Example? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how Chef/idempotency work. Writing a file to disk does not assert a command exists, nor does it assert the thing should/shouldn't be run. You need to analyze the command and give a proper negation clause.

Comment: I was thinking about creating this "lock file" after my recipe runs, as the last resource in it, and then checking it to prevent re-executing. But as a newbie to chef, misunderstanding is very likely, please add references or links on this subject if you could.

Comment: See also the ark cookbook. Similar to the remote_install cookbook mentioned by Seth below: https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/ark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things to consider in this example. First, consider the following:

You are doing something like this:

```rb
execute 'create directory' do
  command 'mkdir -p /path/on/disk && touch created-directory'
  not_if  { File.exist?('created-directory') }
end
```

If I delete the directory, but not the "lockfile", then this block will not execute. This could be problematic, and is the reason why we discourage such mechanisms. You should be doing something like this instead:

```rb
execute 'create directory' do
  command 'mkdir /path/on/disk'
  not_if  { File.directory?('/path/on/disk') }
end
```

However, this is entirely unnecessary, because Chef has a built-in resource for handling such situations:

```rb
directory '/path/on/disk'
```

---

From your example, it seems like you are trying to download, extract, and install a resource. You should really leverage the built-in Chef resources for this, as then you need-not worry about said guards:

```rb
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/whatever.tar.gz" do
  source   'https://something.com/file.tar.gz'
  action   :create_if_missing
  notifies :run, 'execute[extract]', :immediately
end

execute 'extract' do
  command  "tar -xzf #{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/whatever.tar.gz"
  action   :nothing
  notifies :run, 'execute[compile]', :immediately
end

execute 'compile' do
  command "./configure && make && make install"
  action  :nothing
end
```

---

You should also look at the [`remote_install`](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/remote_install) community cookbook, which provides a handy resource:

```rb
remote_install 'bash' do
  source 'http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3.tar.gz'
  version '4.3'
  checksum 'afc687a28e0e24dc21b988fa159ff9dbcf6b7caa92ade8645cc6d5605cd024d4'
  build_command './configure'
  compile_command 'make'
  install_command 'make install'
en
```

Comment: @sethvargo +1E6 for the remote_install cookbook. This page is the search result that caught my eye when I was searching for just such a cookbook.